# Looking for an elegant way to load JS and execute it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, google-translate

I'm new into JavaScript and I really like jQuery and hate when it comes to writing some cumbersome code to get simple things done.

I'm currently trying to load an external JS dynamically and execute it (to communicate with Google Translate API).

The sample code creates a `script` tag, sets its `src` and appends it to document's `head` to execute it:

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
newScript.src = source;

// When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

I wonder if there's any one-liner in jQuery for this.

Comment: There is (see answers), but if you just put it in a function yourself, you will also need to only write it once. :)

Comment: Yup—I just meant I come from a different background (.NET) and so I don't want to spread custom functions across my code when there is a generally used method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.getScript('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + $('#sourceText').html());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1):

**[HeadJS](http://headjs.com/)** is made for such use, this is easy and optimized way to include scripts This will helps you sure.

### basic Method: ( took 800ms)

```
<script src="https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/raw/master/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/smith/scripty2/raw/master/lib/prototype.js"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/headjs/www/raw/master/content/test/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/kosmas58/compass-jquery-plugin/raw/master/lib/jslint.js"></script>
```

### using head.js (took 700 ms)

```
<script src="../media/js/head.min.js"></script>

<script>
head.js("https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael.js")
     .js("https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/raw/master/jquery-1.4.4.js")
     .js("https://github.com/smith/scripty2/raw/master/lib/prototype.js")
     .js("https://github.com/headjs/www/raw/master/content/test/jquery-ui.js")
     .js("https://github.com/kosmas58/compass-jquery-plugin/raw/master/lib/jslint.js");
</script>
```

**[see the testcase](http://headjs.com/test/script.html)**

Comment: I'm fine with what jQuery currently offers, but this is a nice addition in case I needed something more complex. Thanks!